# Finding month/year between 2 dates

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to find out if I have a month/year such as April 2016, how I can find out if it's between 2 dates such as 12/14/15 to 6/12/16. If the month/year is between the 2 dates, I need it to put "x".  I would like this to work without using VBA if possible.

Comment: What do you want the answer to be if the dates are 12/14/15 and 04/25/16?  Does the month need to be completed before the end date?  Do you need to check for that condition?  Why do you need a VBA solution (there's nothing in the problem that requires it)?  What do you want VBA to do that's different from using basic functions?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a simple IF statement ...

[image]

`=IF(AND(A2>B2,A2<C2),"x","")`

If you really want to look only at month and year, but not the date, then it is a little more complex ...

`=IF(AND(OR(YEAR(A3)>YEAR(B3),AND(YEAR(A3)=YEAR(B3),MONTH(A3)>MONTH(B3))),OR(YEAR(A3)<YEAR(C3),AND(YEAR(A3)=YEAR(C3),MONTH(A3)<MONTH(C3)))),"x","")`